# Form Displays for one page, none of the others

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an issue that is baffling me right now. I have a form for making posts and doing image uploads on a page. The page populates with different user information based on the user retrieved from the database. The form works on one profile, but doesn't display on any other profiles and it's baffling me as to why that is happening. Here is the form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name='newPost-<?=$username?>' method='post' action='utilities/newWallPost.php'>
    < textarea name="postText"></textarea>
    < br />
    < input type='file' id='upload' name='upload[]' multiple=""/>
    < input type='hidden' name='recipient' value='<?=$username?>'/>
    < input type='submit' value='Post' name='btn_upload'/>
    < /div>
    < div id="newPost">
        < a href="#" id="newPostLink">Create new post</a>
< /form>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? At first I thought it was a naming convention with the form so I set it to append the username to the form name but it still is just not displaying for some reason.

Edit: Additional Info, when I try and submit the form (the inputs of which are displayed) on the profiles that are not displaying the actual form tag, the system tries to do a get to the same page (rather than to utilities/wallNewWallPost.php). Strange.

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. For example, you have a closing `</div>` with no opening tag - that can easily mess up the layout

Comment: Look at the html source which is output on the failing accounts.

Comment: Whats with all the spaces in the tags?

Comment: The html source on the failing accounts just displays the textarea, br, the inputs and the newpost div but not the form. It's really odd. The spaces are just because stackoverflow was telling me it wouldn't display the tags originally in the post preview and then i put spaces in and it displayed in the preview.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the above code you have typed in, into a new .html document and the form did not display.

I believe the form was not working because of the spaces in the tags.

So I modified it slightly & it worked for me:
[link here](http://codepad.org/PSdUq4t4)